MAUI .NET 8 - Xamarin Migrated project
I have created a new MAUI .NET 8 project and migrated the Xamarin forms project code.
In my project, I used RelativeLayout for UI design on all the pages, now this RelativeLayout is outdated in MAUI.
I used the Compatability namespace to use RelativeLayout in my MAUI project. However, the RelativeLayout is not working properly in MAUI. the position of elements in RelativeLayout working weirdly.
My question is,
RelativeLayout will work properly in MAUI or not?
Do I need to strictly not use RelativeLayout in MAUI? If yes what is the recommended layout in MAUI which similar/alternative to RelativeLayout?

I mean RelativeLayout was bad in Xamarin Forms itself so its better you stop using it ASAP


RelativeLayout will work properly in MAUI or not?
Do I need to strictly not use RelativeLayout in MAUI? If yes what is
the recommended layout in MAUI which similar/alternative to
RelativeLayout?

About RelativeLayout, you can refer to this case: Since RelativeLayeout is not recommended to use in .Net Maui, what techniques would replace it?. You can use Grid Layout or create custom layout.

With Grid Layout, we can place an element with an absolute position? like we do in RelativeLayout. For example, how do I achieve the below RelativeLayout code in Grid Layout, Y Position: return parent.Height - (parent.Height > parent.Width ? parent.Height : parent.Width) * 0.08;

With Grid Layout, we can place an element with an absolute position? No, Grid Layout can't do that. But Gird can use Padding, HorizontalOptions, ColumnDefinitions, RowDefinitions.... with  AbsoluteLayout together to achieve the effect that RelativeLayout can do.

Well, if the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue :)
